# pasar valor a un select desde javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

como puedo poner un valor a un option value
**index.html**

```
            <select id="situacion" name="situacion" class="form-control">
            <option value="activo" select= "selected">val(data.situacion)</option> 
            <option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option>
            </select>
```

**javascript**

```
                var idTelefono = $('#idTelefono').val(data.idTelefono),
                situacion = $('#situacion').val(data.situacion);
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes cambiar el value de una etiqueta option desde JQuery con el método .val y cambiar su texto con .text o .html en caso de necesitar html enriquecido.

```
// JQuery
const idTelefono = 'algo'
if(idTelefono) {
  $('#selectDefault').val(idTelefono).html(idTelefono)
}

// HTML
<select id="situacion" name="situacion" class="form-control">
<option value="activo" select= "selected" id="selectDefault">texto</option> 
<option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option></select>
```

Comment: esto es lo que estoy intentando hacer.<option value="activo" select= "selected" id="selectDefault">VALOR DE LA VARIABLE</option>

Answer (score 0):

Utilizando `jQuery` con el metodo `.append()` [info](http://api.jquery.com/append/) y `template-literal` [info](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/template_strings) añades un `option` con el valor de tu variable, cualquier duda hazla saber.

```js
let nuevoOption = 'Ausente';

$('#situacion').append(`<option value="${nuevoOption}">${nuevoOption}</option>`);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="situacion" name="situacion" class="form-control">
<option value="activo" select= "selected" id="selectDefault">texto</option> 
<option value="Inactivo">Inactivo</option></select>
```

Comment: En caso de querer añadir otros elementos al select la mejor opción desde mi punto de vista es utilizar .innerHTML en lugar de .append por la manipulación del DOM. Usando nodos el tiempo de ejecución es mucho mayor. Más info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18393981/append-vs-html-vs-innerhtml-performance